# Calling Java from XSL (SAXON)

Tags: java, xslt, stylesheet, transformation, saxon

I'm trying to use the Saxon processor from java. I'm using the the **saxon9ee.jar** inside saxonee9-3-0-11j.zip (just downloaded, no license - is that needed so it'll work?)

Their ******** resources can be found here:
http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensibility/functions/instance-methods.xml

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensibility/functions/staticmethods.xml

My xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">  
        <xsl:value-of select="dateUtils:getCurrentFullDate()" 
              xmlns:dateUtils="java:com.macfaq.math.SimpleSaxon"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My java file:

```
package com.macfaq.math;
public class SimpleSaxon {
public static final String YMDTHMS = "yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss";
    public static String getCurrentFullDate() {
        return (new SimpleDateFormat(YMDTHMS).format(new Date()));
    }

}
```

My input XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<date format="yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss" year="2000" month="4" day="27"/>
```

My main java file:

```
public class SaxonTransf {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
            "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
    String foo_xml = "in.xml"; // input xml
    String foo_xsl = "transf.xsl"; // input xsl

    TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(
            new File(foo_xsl)));
    transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File(foo_xml)), 
        new StreamResult(System.out));

}
```

Error:
XTDE1425: Cannot find a matching 0-argument function named
  {java:com.macfaq.math.SimpleSaxon}getCurrentFullDate(). The namespace URI and local name
  are recognized, but the number of arguments is wrong in built-in template rule.

Has anyone had any luck with calling custom java functions from XSL while using this wonderful processor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run Saxon using the Saxon-EE JAR file but with no license, then (in theory at least) it should behave exactly like Saxon-HE, which means this style of extension function call is not supported.

If you're running from the command line, the -TJ option will give you more detailed diagnostics detailing the search for a matching function.

Comment: When using Saxon-HE, the exception says the HE version doesn't support extension functions (more or less). Without changing any of the code, but just the Saxon library, I get the error above.

I'm running it from Eclipse and I've tried setting the -TJ parameter, but the output seems the same.