# Saxon cannot find function: current-group

Tags: xml, maven, xslt-2.0, saxon, xslt-grouping

I am trying to use Saxon with XSLT stylesheets and using the code examples in the XSLT2 spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group)

```
<table xsl:version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <tr>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>City List</th>
    <th>Population</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="cities/city" group-by="@country">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@country"/></td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/@name" separator=", "/>
      </td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/@pop)"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</table>
```

I'm using the following in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
  <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
  <version>9.6.0-3</version>
</dependency>
```

and the code to run it is:

```
    @Test
    public void testSaxonXslt2GroupTest1() throws Exception {

        File xml_file = Fixtures.XSLT2_TEST1_XML;
        File xsl_file = Fixtures.XSLT2_TEST1_XSL;


        TransformerFactory tfactory = net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsl_file));
        File saxonDir = new File("target/saxon/");
        saxonDir.mkdirs();
        try {
            transformer.transform(new StreamSource(xml_file),  
                new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(new File(saxonDir, "test1.xml"))));
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This throws an error on the output console

```
SystemId Unknown; Line #13; Column #70; Could not find function: current-group
SystemId Unknown; Line #13; Column #70; function token not found.
(Location of error unknown)java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Is this function missing in the Saxon version I am using, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't think this causes trouble, but why did you specify `version="1.0"`?

Comment: I think this is a transcription error and it should be 2.0. I'll check against my actual code

Comment: I *am* running it locally with xsl:version="2.0"

Comment: I am trying to reproduce this but as the XSLT has `<xsl:value-of select="current-group()/@name" separator=",">` the sample is not even well-formed. When I correct the code to `<xsl:value-of select="current-group()/@name" separator=","/>` then Saxon outputs a result, at least running it from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. My code has well formed XML/XSL. I will repaste...

Comment: I can now run the code just fine with Saxon 9.6.0.3 HE from the command line, it does not report any error. Someone else will need to check or explain why it does not work for you with your Java code.

Comment: Now, the stylesheet is definitely correct and produces correct output - so you can rule it out as the source of error.

Comment: Thanks for your time. It is useful to know that Saxon can do the processing if it is set up correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAXP strikes again! The problem is, you are not actually running Saxon.

When you do this:

```
factory = net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newInstance();
```

it really looks as if you are calling a Saxon method, doesn't it? But in Java, static methods can't be overridden in this way (I would if I could...). You are simply calling the newInstance() method on the base class, which searches the classpath for the first XSLT processor it finds lying around. If you want to invoke Saxon explicitly, it's much better to avoid the classpath search by doing

```
factory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
```

Comment: Thanks. All makes sense now. There's the danger that there's more than one way to do this and so I have ended up cutting and pasting from known examples and confusing things. Hopefully the example will help others to get it right

Answer (score 1):

I have now found something that works.

```
    @Test
    public void testSaxonXslt2GroupTest1() throws Exception {
//      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925483/calling-java-from-xsl-saxon  

        File xml_file = Fixtures.XSLT2_TEST1_XML;
        File xsl_file = Fixtures.XSLT2_TEST1_XSL;
        LOG.debug(FileUtils.readFileToString(xsl_file));
```

// replacing the fully qualified class name with a property approach, seems to work

```
        System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
                "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
        TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

//

```
  Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsl_file));
            File saxonDir = new File("target/saxon/");
            saxonDir.mkdirs();
            try {
                transformer.transform(new StreamSource(xml_file),  
                    new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(new File(saxonDir, "test1.xml"))));
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I had thought that using the precise constructor would be sufficient, but it seems not.

Comment: I think you can either directly do `TransformerFactory tFactory = new TransformerFactoryImpl();` with an `import net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl;` or you indeed need to set the system property. The `newInstance` method is inherited and there is no override for it in http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/TransformerFactoryImpl.html.

Comment: Thanks - that seems to explain it - maybe it should be overridden or trapped somehow

Comment: If you think that should be fixed in Saxon, you could report a bug to Saxonica or notify @MichaelKay.